# How to add minutes to time in R

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have a data frame with time(e.g: 10.24) and minute(e.g:31) columns.

I want to add those two columns. Resultant column would be 10.24+31(min)=10.55. I tried with [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) but it is giving wrong times.

```
dput(stack_data)
structure(list(time = c("10:24", "10:40"), timeInMin = c(31L, 
23L)), row.names = c(19L, 23L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried like this:

```
stack_data$time <- (hm(stack_data$time))
stack_data$timeInMin <- hms((stack_data$time) + (stack_data$timeInMin))
```

Output:

```
time         timeInMin
10H 24M 0S    10:24:31
10H 40M 0S    10:40:23
```

I am getting a wrong answer. Can you please suggest me to how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `as.ITime` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
stack_data$time <- as.ITime(paste0(stack_data$time, ":00"))
stack_data$timeInMin <- stack_data$time +
                    as.ITime(paste0("00:", stack_data$timeInMin, ":00"))
stack_data$timeInMin
#[1] "10:55:00" "11:03:00"
```

Or using `hm`

```
library(lubridate)
hm(stack_data$time)  + minutes(stack_data$timeInMin)
#[1] "10H 55M 0S" "10H 63M 0S"
```

Comment: @Magie could you show an example `as.ITime("23:00:00") + as.ITime("01:25:00")#
[1] "24:25:00"`

Comment: If time is 13:24 and minutes to add is 20 , I have to get 13:44, Is it work for `ITime`

Comment: @Magie it  works `as.ITime("13:24:00") + as.ITime("00:20:00")#
[1] "13:44:00"` if you check my code, I am `paste`ing the `00` at the left and right of the minutes with `:` so that `as.ITime` can pick up the format

Comment: while adding 64 minutes the time it is giving **NA**. Example, ``` 07:47:00 + (00,64,00) ``` It is giving **NA** instead of 08:51:00. Why?

Comment: @Magie I guess you need to convert that minute > 60 to hour year minute il.e. ` `as.ITime("01:04:00") + as.ITime("07:47:00")#
#[1] "08:51:00"  the issue is with `as.ITime("00:64:00")#
[1] NA`

Comment: It working now.Converted 64 minutes to 01:04:00 format  . Thank you