# Add minutes as as.ITime() to as.ITime() as fixed time

Tags: r, dataframe, time, data.table, lubridate

I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60354977/how-to-add-minutes-to-time-in-r) but encountered several issues.

I have

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  OnsetTime TotalSleepTime
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 22:55:00             448
2 23:13:00             420
3 01:45:00             327
4 00:13:00             448
5 01:05:00             349
6 23:50:00             466
```

`q$TotalSleepTime` is in minutes, and I want to add those minutes to `q$OnsetTime` and create a new column with that time.

I tried

```
q %>% mutate(newtime = as.ITime(OnsetTime) + as.ITime(TotalSleepTime))
```

But that does not produce the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   TotalSleepTime newtime 
            <dbl> <ITime> 
 1            448 23:02:28
 2            420 23:20:00
 3            327 01:50:27
 4            448 00:20:28
 5            349 01:10:49
 6            466 23:57:46
```

I am seeking a solution in either `data.table` or `lubridate`.

I also tried

```
 q %>% mutate(
         TotalSleepTime_new = as.integer(TotalSleepTime/60),
         newtime = hms(OnsetTime) + hours(TotalSleepTime_new))
```

Data

```
q <- structure(list(OnsetTime = c("22:55:00", "23:13:00", "01:45:00", 
"00:13:00", "01:05:00", "23:50:00"), TotalSleepTime = c(448, 
420, 327, 448, 349, 466)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding time in R is by the second. Since you have minutes, we need to multiply.

```r
library(dplyr)
q %>%
  mutate(newtime = as.ITime(OnsetTime) + 60*TotalSleepTime)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   OnsetTime TotalSleepTime newtime 
#   <chr>              <dbl> <ITime> 
# 1 22:55:00             448 30:23:00
# 2 23:13:00             420 30:13:00
# 3 01:45:00             327 07:12:00
# 4 00:13:00             448 07:41:00
# 5 01:05:00             349 06:54:00
# 6 23:50:00             466 31:36:00

library(data.table)
as.data.table(q)[, newtime := as.ITime(OnsetTime) + 60*TotalSleepTime][]
#    OnsetTime TotalSleepTime  newtime
#       <char>          <num>  <ITime>
# 1:  22:55:00            448 30:23:00
# 2:  23:13:00            420 30:13:00
# 3:  01:45:00            327 07:12:00
# 4:  00:13:00            448 07:41:00
# 5:  01:05:00            349 06:54:00
# 6:  23:50:00            466 31:36:00
```